# Datagrid's hover slow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a grid containing 2  radio buttons and 2 datagrids. When a radiobutton is checked I set one datagrid's visibility to Visible and the other to Collapsed.

My datagrid contains only 15 rows but it is really slow, when my mouse is over there is a huge delay before I can actually see the hover effect. It works fine on all my other pages but not on this one (which has a lot of other components).

```
<Grid Name="conteneur2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,5">
    <DataGrid EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Style="{StaticResource StyleDataGrid}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_Data}" MaxWidth="2000" MaxHeight="1500" x:Name="dataGrid1" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Num" Width="40" Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="160*" MinWidth="160" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value1}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="2pts" Width="55" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value2}" SortMemberPath="Stats.TirsReussis" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value3}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="55" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value4}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value5}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="55" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value6}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value7}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value8}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value9}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value10}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="45" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value11}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value12}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value13}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value14}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value15}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="45" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value16}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Binding="{Binding Stats.Value17}" SortMemberPath="Stats._Minute" IsReadOnly="True" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Why does it become so slow ? What can I do to improve the performance ?

Thank you